# Sync name and address with drupal user page via civicrm webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am trying to sync the CiviCRM first name and address fields to a Drupal user account page but I cannot figure out the configuration. I am hoping it is something simple that I am missing out.

Scenario - We have a user who submits a webform with the first name, last name, address and phone number fields from CiviCRM. This is attached to an Ubercart product and when submitted the user has successfully purchased the product which comes with access to drupal to add some content. However, when the user logs in all the Drupal User fields are blank i.e. they need to be refilled again. Is there a simple way to sync them.

I have tried to the profiles section in CiviCRM but it actually add new fields to the profile page and does not sync them. Perhaps the CiviCRM roles sync is the right way to go? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the instructions in this [blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms) about setting up a webform so that it adds a 'tag' to the contact, and Drupal Rules then use that contact to create a Drupal User for the contact (and log them in instantly if required) might be helpful to you.